# Install texlive from download

Tags: texlive, installing, windows

I tried installing texlive on a Windows 10 computer, and it failed with a cryptic error message, several times. Frustrated, I tried the option which only downloads and unpacks it.

Is there something I can do from here so I can continue the installation attempts without waiting every time multiple hours for new downloads? Or can I "install" it manually, for example by adding the now-existing latex.exe to the path or the registry?

Comment: I would first suggest you to download the [`ISO` file](https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire.html) once and make a copy of it. Have you followed [TeX-Live site instructions](https://www.tug.org/texlive/windows.html) for Windows? When does installation fail? What is the error you get?

Comment: @ebo I got the installer from here: https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html. When I start it with administrator rights (virus scanner turned off), I get through the wizard (I leave all the options as they are preselected) and it starts the installation. The installation seems to work, counting through the packages, but takes several hours. When I come back to it later, it greets me with some noninformative error like "installation failed, try again" (always the same, I forgot the exact text). I have been through it 3-4 times, and it would take me half a day to reproduce the error.

Comment: The error message would be nice. It might also be an idea to use a better mirror. Where in the world are you? Exactly which of the two windows installers are you using? There is an exe and a zip. Thirdly, if you have the space, you can rsync the entire installation archive to local disk and installing from there. That should make reinstalls a lot faster. I tend to do the later and thus have a local archive for other pcs to install from. You can even place the tlnet stuff on a USB (though for Windows I'd still copy the contents of the USB to local disk before installing)

Comment: @daleif it is not about the mirror, it is my local network connection which makes it so slow. I used the .exe installer. How would rsync help? I do have all the files now, the "download option" only worked. What I don't know is how to do whatever else the installer would have done besides copying the files to disk.

Comment: Rsync takes the slow network out of the equation. The installer has to grap 3500 packages for your installation (depending on scheme) each time you attempt an install. Now imagine if those 3500 installation files were already on your computer. That is what rsync can do, create a local mirror (of a mirror that provides rsync access). You can run the rsync overnight. Look up rsync on Wikipedia, it us a super useful tool.

Comment: @daleif OK, I see. I was wondering if there is a way to continue from where I am, without the need to download all that stuff yet again. Running the installer to fetch the files again - from the network or from a mirror downloaded on my computer - is useless, since the error message contains practically no information.

Comment: In my experience that continue thing does not work well. It seems to start over each time no matter what (annoyingly)

Comment: You must be thinking of something different. There is no option to continue. The installation did not stop in the middle telling me that I can continue. The first few times, it would run through, finishing with the error message, and there would be no visible trace of it having run, certainly no half-installation at the path I specified. So the last time, I chose to run the installer selecting the option "download only". This finished without an error. So I am not in the middle of an installation.

Comment: Note that there should be a `.log` file from the failed installations.

Comment: @cfr where? I see none in the folder where the installer is, and none in the folder where the installation should have happened. Although the download possibly overwrote that one. Where should I look for the log file?

Comment: Unless it doesn't log on Windows, which would be strange, you should have something like `<path to installation directory>/2016/install-tl.log` where `2016` is the current edition's directory. I have `2016/install-tl.log`, `2015/install-tl.log` and so on back, for all the editions I currently have installed.